# Could not load file or assembly 'ClearScriptV8' or one of its dependencies. is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1)

Tags: clearscript

It is working on local IIS on Windows 7, but give this error on Windows Server 2012 IIS 8.5.

ClearScript version: 5.4.0.0

C++ Redistributable 2013 Installed.

[image: C++ Redistributable 2013 Installed]

I've used AssemblyResolver from https://clearscript.codeplex.com/discussions/438696

Getting error BadImageFormatException: Could not load file or assembly 'ClearScriptV8' or one of its dependencies. is not a valid Win32 application. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x800700C1).

Before that I was getting error about library not found in root of web project.

Is it working for anyone on IIS 8.5? I was forced to move to ClearScriptV8, after problems with Noesis, that works in IIS 8.5 very unstable (CompileScript error in 1/3 of requests on same page). In IIS 7.5 Noesis worked perfectly.

Comment: Just a thought: Make sure your assembly resolver loads the correct assembly for the process architecture (32-bit vs. 64-bit). You can check it via `Environment.Is64BitProcess` and load ClearScriptV8-32.dll or ClearScriptV8-64.dll as appropriate.

Comment: Tried both, tried Enable 32 bit option in AppPool. Is it work for you in IIS 8.5?

Comment: Working in Console Application on server. Something with IIS looks like.

Comment: It's working on IIS 8.5 without an assembly resolver. I'm just deploying ClearScriptV8-\*.dll and v8-\*.dll at the application root and installing the Visual C++ redistributables.

Comment: Which version did you deploy?

Comment: Found what was the problem, ClearScript needed C++ redistributable 2012, while ConsoleApp worked with 2013 one. Thats strange, to make sure install all 4.